Visual Studio Code проблемы с удалением файлов из проекта
При попытке удаления файла из проекта VSC клавишей "del" или из контекстного меню, в строке состояния бесконечно крутится кружок и пишет "deleting file". Но файл не удаляется. Раньше все работало. ОС Linux. Пробовал скидать настройки, устанавливать обновление, запускать через sudo. При этом через терминал файл удаляется без проблем но кружок удаления в строке состояния не перестает крутится.
